# How to get the selected video path?

Tags: android-studio, video, upload

this code below uploads the recorded video to server

All what i want to do is : I just want to upload video from Galery.

I have added new Button to load video from Storage, the code can play the selected video in Viedeoview.

After that I try to get the filePath like below but i did not get it correctly :
[image]

```
    public void Load_Video(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setType("video/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Complete action using"), 99 ); 
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode != RESULT_OK) return;

    switch (requestCode) {

        case 99:

            Uri  mVideoCaptureUri = data.getData();
            vidPreview.setVideoURI(mVideoCaptureUri);
            vidPreview.start();                
            filePath=mVideoCaptureUri.toString();
            Toast.makeText(Main.this, "filePath : " +filePath, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
    }
}
```

source : [Source of complet demo here :](http://www.androidhive.info/2014/12/android-uploading-camera-image-video-to-server-with-progress-bar/)

**After I have selected a video from gallery, how to get the path ?**

Comment: Take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37761884/334402

Comment: I have tested the function there of Answer : generatePath, but I get the path like that : **/document/video:16754**   but this is no video path !!!

Comment: the video path should have at the end the video type like that : **path+filename.mp4**

Comment: thanks, problem fixed, after i did small changes on the function there

Comment: can u publish ur solution ?